# Bind click event not work in dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I call call ajax and when success i build button elements.
Like this :

```
...
    .done(function(data) {
                $('#data-message').empty();
                // console.log(data);
                $('#total_notification_msg').html(data.total);

                $.each(data.data, function(index, value) {
                  // console.log(value);
                  var redirectRead = '{{ route("adm1n.message.show", ":id") }}'
                  redirectRead = redirectRead.replace(":id", value.id);

                  var pesan = value.message.substr(0,100);

    $('#data-message').append('<button id='reply' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' style='margin-top:5px;'>Reply</button>");
                });
              })
    ...
```

But, i can't add click event on `#reply` button.

I already using `on` or `click` event :

```
$(document).on('click', '#reply', function() {
     alert('Reply here');
});

// or this ...

$('#reply').click(function() {
     alert('Reply here');
});
```

But it still not works.

Please help, thank you ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes properly when creating elements using string.

```
$('#data-message').append('<button class="reply btn btn-default btn-xs" style="margin-top:5px;">Reply</button>");
```

And use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically

```
$('#data-message').on('click', '.reply', function() {
     alert('Reply here');
});
```

Since Identifiers must be unique, use class instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change two things:

1. correct quotes.
2. change id to class.

---

```
$('#data-message').append("<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs reply' style='margin-top:5px;'>Reply</button>");
//-----------------change here-----------------------------------^^^^^
```

Because you are in loop and you are duplicating same ids.

change your event binding to class:

```
$(document).on('click', '.reply', function() {
     alert('Reply here');
});
```